# How to modify DateTimeImmuable?

Tags: php

I'm stuck with a problem with using DateTimeImmutable in a project with Symfony. I'd like to add 21 days to a date without changing the first date. But I have this error :

```
DateTimeImmutable::__construct(): Argument #1 ($datetime) must be of type string, DateTime given
```

I tried to change the dateTime to string (My tries are in comment in the code below).

```php
// My class Borrowing

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\BorrowingDetails;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\BorrowingRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BorrowingRepository::class)
 */
class Borrowing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateStartBorrowing;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateLimitReturn;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateStartBorrowing(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateStartBorrowing;
    }

    public function setDateStartBorrowing(\DateTimeInterface $dateStartBorrowing): self
    {
        $this->dateStartBorrowing = $dateStartBorrowing;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|BorrowingDetails[]
     */
    public function getBorrowingDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->borrowingDetails;
    }

    public function addBorrowingDetail(BorrowingDetails $borrowingDetail): self
    {
        if (!$this->borrowingDetails->contains($borrowingDetail)) {
            $this->borrowingDetails[] = $borrowingDetail;
            $borrowingDetail->setMyBorrowing($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateLimitReturn(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateLimitReturn;
    }

    public function setDateLimitReturn(\DateTimeInterface $dateLimitReturn): self
    {
        $this->dateStartBorrowing = $dateLimitReturn;

        return $this;
    }

    // I tried to add this function
    // public function __toString() {
    //     return $this->getDateStartBorrowing();
    // }
}
```

```php
// This is my BorrowingController

$dateStartBorrowing = new \DateTime();
// I Tried : $dateStartBorrowing->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$dateLimitReturn = new \DateTimeImmutable($dateStartBorrowing);
$dateLimitReturn->modify('+21 days');
$dateLimitReturn->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            
$borrowing = new Borrowing();
$borrowing->setDateStartBorrowing($dateStartBorrowing);
$borrowing->setDateLimitReturn($dateLimitReturn);
```

Does somebody have an answer ?

And if I manage to change it into a string does the rest of my code will works, because in my database it musts be a datetime ?

Comment: `DateTimeImmutable` is immutable. Doing `$dateLimitReturn->modify('+21 days');` but not storing the result will have no side-effects

Comment: Do you mean I must write this ? :
```
$dateStartBorrowing = new \DateTime();
$dateLimitReturn = $dateStartBorrowing;
$dateLimitReturn->modify('+21 days');
$dateLimitReturn->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: The whole point of `DateTimeImmutable` as opposed to `DateTime` *is* that it's immutable - it can't be changed once created. If you call `modify()` you return a new object, but don't modify the existing one.

Comment: Please reduce the shared code to the neccessary parts - to me, this does not look related to Symfony after all. Also, how is this related to [tag:tostring]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\DateTimeImmutable` does not modify the original object, but instead gives you a **new one** back.

```php
$today = new \DateTimeImmutable('now');
$inTenDays = $today->modify('+10 days'); 
dump($today); // is still 'now'
dump($inTenDays); // 10 days in future
```

So there are two options:

1. Store changed in a new variable
2. Don't use `\DateTimeImmutable` in this particular case

For 1)

```php
$dateStartBorrowing = new \DateTime(); // which is now

$dateLimitReturn = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($dateStartBorrowing); // now it's an instance of DateTimeImmutable 
$modified = $dateLimitReturn->modify('+21 days');
...
$borrowing->setDateLimitReturn($modified);
```

For2)

```php
$dateLimitReturn = clone $dateStartBorrowing; // you need a copy so you can modify $dateLimitReturn whithout changing the $dateStartBorrowing
$dateLimitReturn->modify('+21 days'); // $dateLimitReturn is now modified and 21 days in future
...
$borrowing->setDateLimitReturn($dateLimitReturn);
```

you also could do it shorter...

```php
$inTwentyOneDays = new \DateTimeImmutable('now + 21 days');
$borrowing->setDateLimitReturn($inTwentyOneDays);
```

UPDATE:

TBH, I don't know your business logic, but I don't see any benefit of using \DateTimeImmutable insted of regular \DateTime in this case.

Why?

Since property declaration of your entity is:
`@ORM\Column(type="datetime")`
after reading from database, all $entity->getDateLimitReturn() will be regular \DateTime anyway...unless you have some custom doctrine types which